# Laravel setup one form to save to two tables

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get one form to save two tables. The form I have collects data for equipment "check in/out" and collects pictures for that check in/out. The string data collected is stored in the `Traffic` table while the image data will be stored in the `Details` table.

The `Traffic` entry for the check in/out can have many `Details`.
The `Details` belongs to a specific `Traffic` entry.

The way I have it set up I keep getting `BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::detail()` error.

Here is my TrafficController:

```
        auth()->user()->traffic()->create([
            'branch' => $data['branch'],
            'io' => $data['io'],
            'make' => $data['make'],
            'model' => $data['model'],
            'sn' => $data['sn'],
            'customer' => $data['customer'],
        ]);

        if ($upload['isSuccess']) {
            foreach($upload['files'] as $key=>$item) {
                $upload['files'][$key] = array(
                    auth()->user()->traffic()->detail()->create([
                        'extension' => $upload['files'][$key]['extension'],
                        'format' => $upload['files'][$key]['format'],
                        'file' => 'storage/' . $uploadDir . $upload['files'][$key]['name'],
                        'name' => $upload['files'][$key]['name'],
                        'size' => $upload['files'][$key]['size'],
                        'size2' => $upload['files'][$key]['size2'],
                        'title' => $upload['files'][$key]['title'],
                        'type' => $upload['files'][$key]['type'],
                        'url' => 'http://localhost:8000/storage/' . $uploadDir . $upload['files'][$key]['name'],
                    ]));
            }
        } else {
            foreach($upload['warnings'] as $error) {
                // echo $error . '<br>';
            }
        }
```

My Traffic Model

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function detail()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Detail::class);
    }
```

My Detail Model

```
    public function traffic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Traffic::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the user can have many Traffic resources, you aren't specifying which Traffic resource you want to add the Detail resource to. You should assign your new Traffic resource to a variable when you create it:

```
$traffic = auth()->user()->traffic()->create([
    'branch' => $data['branch'],
    'io' => $data['io'],
    'make' => $data['make'],
    'model' => $data['model'],
    'sn' => $data['sn'],
    'customer' => $data['customer'],
]);
```

And the when you are creating a new Detail resource `(might want to change the relationship from detail to details since it suggests many like your hasMany relationship where detail suggets hasOne)` you could call:

```
$traffic->detail()->create([
    ...
]);
```

I also notice you are looping through an array to create new Detail resources. There is actually a `createMany()` pointer function which can help simplify that process. You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method).

Comment: Thank you Sawyer for your help that did it. Still learning thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Mike No problem, glad I could help. Happy learning!